# which layout for 3buttons/3states android app

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I need to have an activity with the [layout](http://cristianbell.com/tmp/app_layout.png). 
I have 3 issues: 
- choosing the best/easies layout for this. I tried relativeLayout and Linear (with layout_weight), but it's not easy to arange the items like in the screenshot. Would TableLayout be a solution? 
- The buttons have to be like in the screenshot, images. I tried using buttons with drawableLeft="@drawable/..." but it didn't work. I am thinking of just adding TextView with ab background and make them clickabke. 
- the black vertical line. At first I wanted to make the background of the main layout black and have 2 layouts on top with a small margin between them to simulate the black vertical line.

The code I have is below, but the Images are all on top of each other..

Thanks for any tips/ideas!

```
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.huberlin.taptool.TT_Classes.Designer_Classes.TT_Settings2"
android:background="#000000">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="35"
    android:background="#EE3333">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cfg_about"
        android:text="@string/tt_cfg_aboutBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/disabled2x"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"

        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cfg_save"
        android:text="@string/tt_cfg_saveBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/disabled2x"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cfg_items"
        android:text="@string/tt_cfg_saveBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/disabled2x"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="65"
    android:background="#EFEFF4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0.1dp">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue with the images just specify the orientation of the parent LinearLayout to vertical.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="35"
    android:background="#EE3333"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cfg_about"
        android:text="@string/tt_cfg_aboutBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/disabled2x"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"

        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cfg_save"
        android:text="@string/tt_cfg_saveBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/disabled2x"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cfg_items"
        android:text="@string/tt_cfg_saveBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/disabled2x"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this can help you.